# Removing dynamic component from jQuery messes up the ViewContainerRef container

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jsplumb

I have an angular 2+ app in which I am creating a bunch of dynamic components like so -

```
@ViewChild("containerNode", { read: ViewContainerRef }) cardContainer;

const factory = this.ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CardComponent);
const ref = this.cardContainer.createComponent(factory);
```

I'm using jsPlumb (jQuery version) with which I am drawing these created components on to a canvas. Once these elements are part of the jsPlumb instance, jsPlumb provides options to remove the elements, add endpoints, etc.

Now, on a user (click) event, I am removing the element the user clicked on, like so -

```
this.jsPlumbInstance.remove(ref.location.nativeElement);
```

Internally I assume this is just a jQuery remove. The problem I am facing is, after I remove this element using the above code, I'm not able to add any new components using the ViewContainerRef. After this line has executed, when I do this

```
const factory = this.ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CardComponent);
const ref = this.cardContainer.createComponent(factory);
```

the ref.location.nativeElement's parent nodes are null. I suspect that removing a component using the jQuery remove is somehow messing up the container and does not add new components properly to the parent. Note, I HAVE TO do a jsPlumb.remove as there are several other related events that will be fired internally by jsPlumb which must all execute when a component is removed from it (like all edges connected to it should also be removed, etc.)

Does anyone know what is happening here and how it can be fixed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess the issue is you use Angular to create your (component) view which is inserted and supposed to be managed by Angular but unexpectedly removed by your other JavaScript library that Angular is not aware of. Have you tried to `detach/remove` your view using Angular way? something like `this.cardContainer.detach()` to remove your dynamic component then do whatever you need with jsPlumb? Would be helpful if you could share (html/ts) how/where your dynamic component is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried remove(). That resulted in a conflict since whichever's remove happens second, complains that the element has already been removed. But detached solved the problem. I did something like this.cardContainer.detach(this.cardContainer.indexOf(card.componentRef));
Please post your reply as an answer and I will mark the question answered.

Comment: Thanks. Just added the minimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in the above comment. One way to manipulate DOM element created by Angular in Angular way is using `detach()` method of ViewContainerRef class. Something like this:

```
@ViewChild("containerNode", { read: ViewContainerRef }) cardContainer: ViewContainerRef;

...

// To remove/detach component in Angular way
this.cardContainer.detach();
```